# How to set --collector.textfile.directory in node exporter

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm following [this](https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-directory-sizes-with-the-textfile-collector) article about exporting metrics using textfile collector.

I did a text file `/var/lib/node_exporter/textfile_collector/directory_size.prom` with metrics of size of directories, but it doesn't push it to prometheus.

I read that the flag `--collector.textfile.directory` is responsible for the path of the dir to read from. How can I check what is the directory of the collector, and how can I change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

node_exporter service file you must add

> --collector.textfile.directory=/var/lib/node_exporter/textfile_collector

Example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/binary/node_exporter --collector.textfile.directory=/path/to/read/directory

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: * Just a note, in that directory file name should end with `.prom`, and there should be only one `.prom` file , then only Prometheus reads this file

Comment: @ManjuN, that's not true. It will read **all** `.prom` files in that directory. See: https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to provide both --collector.textfile and --collector.textfile.directory=thedir

Comment: It's because you may have used "--collector.disable-defaults" and then enabling a specific collector(--collector.textfile in your example).